# Can we remove vertical scroll from power BI table?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a power BI table that the user want to have it flow down the page instead of having to scroll through it is it possible to remove the vertical scroll bar for Table?
[image]

Comment: No, this is how Power BI works. It is intended to be interactive data analysis tool, not a web page builder.

Comment: ^ unnecessary snarky comment in the modern days of touch devices. 

I'm with you, OP - I'd like to use design fold techniques to show there is more to scroll, rather than the clunky scrollbar. A scrollbar that I cannot style.

There are absolutely use cases for wanting to have more data to scroll without using filters. 

If I find a workaround that doesn't involve a blocking visual, I'll be sure to let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Here are your options:

1. Increase the hight of the visual
2. Reduce font size and row padding
3. Add a filter to reduce the number of rows